# Error in my datetime data field in the RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I face the following problem with my report for Datetime field:

```
#Error
```

---

[image]

I check for null or empty but i always get this error

I try this :

```
=IIf(CDate(Fields!recommendationDate.Value)=CDate("1/1/0001"),Nothing,
 CDate(Fields!recommendationDate.Value).ToShortDateString())
```

---

```
=IIf(FormatDateTime(Fields!recommendationDate.Value,2)=CDate("1/1/0001"),"",FormatDateTime(Fields!recommendationDate.Value.Value,2))
```

---

```
=IIF(Fields!recommendationDate.Value is nothing, nothing,Format(CDate(Fields!recommendationDate.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: have you tried format without `CDate`? I'll run some tests here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IIF(CDATE(IIF(TRIM(Fields!recommendationDate.Value).ToString().Length = 0,
"1/1/0001",
Fields!recommendationDate.Value)).ToString() = CDATE("01/01/0001"),
"",
Format(CDATE(IIF(TRIM(Fields!recommendationDate.Value).ToString().Length = 0,
"1/1/0001",
Fields!recommendationDate.Value)), "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct code would be:

```
IIf(IsNothing(Fields!recommendationDate.Value), "",
              format(Fields!recommendationDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the `IIf` here is similar or the same as `IIf` in Ms Access, but all parts of the expression are executed (condition, true part and false part) irrespective of the outcome.  You might want to try testing the field for `NULL` first using something like `IsNull()`:

```
IIf(IsNull(Fields!recommendationDate.Value), CDate('01/01/0001'), Fields!recommendationDate.Value)
```